# Iota Tipbot for StackEchange?

Tags: discussion, status-declined

How about having a tip bot here in StackExchange, like iTipBot (available on Twitter and Reddit)?

- Is it allowed by StackExchange's policies? Would probably have to monitor comments and answer to them.
- Is it a good idea to have it here? As this is about IOTA, I think it would be cool if people could tip each other with IOTA here. But probably I am alone...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interesting idea, but Stack Exchange would not allow any type of payment or exchange of value in association with providing answers or content. It goes squarely against our philosophy of intrinsic motivations that drive the curation of content by an engaged community as its own reward. Even as a "tip" or an afterthought, we feel it would adversely change the dynamics of the whole site.

Answer (score 12):

I just want to add to Robert's comment that there were two similar discussions on Ethereum SE:

- [Should crypto-bounties be allowed in questions?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/510/87)
- [Is tipping allowed on the Ethereum StackExchange site?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/268/87)

With nine interesting answers. One of them by me was widely appreciated:

> In general, the reward model of stack exchange is pretty straightforward: Good and helpful content get's [upvoted](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). Upvotes generate [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and reputation enables users [privileges](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).
>
> And privileges are important because this site is *run by you*, the community. High reputation enables you [access to moderator tools](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), [protecting questions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions), [deleting posts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) and finally even [access to site analytics](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics).
>
> However, you should be allowed to post a tipping address in your profile. As long as you don't post it along with content or advertise for tipping, you should be okay with that.