# Replace points with Iota transactions

Tags: discussion

What would it take to replace the upvoting/points system on this site with Iota bounties/transactions instead? Iotaqa.com was already created, but it seems like that idea could apply to the many users here

Comment: I think we cannot close this question as a duplicate of a meta question. But perhaps we can close it as "Belongs to meta" and then close the resulting meta question as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, that works @mihi

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange does not allow tip bots (see [this question on meta](https://iota.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/134)), and I believe any other iota bounties fall in the same category.

So to get Iota bounties, you probably have to write your own Q&A site and get users to use it instead of Stack Exchange. (Posting a donation address in the Stack Exchange profile is ok, though).